# How to implement StringTokenizer

Tags: java, string

how to use java stringtokenizer for the below string

"ABC_IMAGE_PICTURE"

i want java to take the blank as a first filedtoo, but stringtokenizer is skipping it. My output should be as imagePICTURE

Any option to get it?.

Comment: post your current code

Comment: **imagePICTURE** or **IMAGE_PICTURE** ?

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you could use.
    String.split("_");